# How to limit the number of parallel executed programs in SLURM

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

I am trying to use slurm to run multiple commands in parallel on my cluster (single node).
This is my situation:

- I have N commands to run
- I have M physical cores in my cluster (M=4)

Since every command requires a physical core, and M < N, I would like that, at most, only M commands are executed simultaneously.

The problem is that all the N commands are executed when I run `sbatch` command. I tried to use `--ntasks` parameter but with no success. Probably I am using the wrong SLURM parameters.

This is the file I am using:

```
############# file name: ./run_parallel_commands.sh #############
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1G

./command-1 &
./command-2 &
# ...
./command-N &
wait
```

And it is executed running:

```
$ sbatch ./run_parallel_commands.sh
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there; the parameters you have should be fine. It's just the execution of the commands which needs work. You must execute the tasks using the `srun` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1G

srun ./command-1 &
srun ./command-2 &
# ...
srun ./command-N &
wait
```

Comment: I completely forgot to put "srun"! Thank you very much

Comment: This would have been a lot easier to diagnose yourself if you had multiple nodes as without "srun" youd have been executing on the node you submitted from rather than compute nodes within the cluster